# call bash script with arguments in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I am trying to execute the following via a python script.  But I am getting an error.  `Unknown option:-a test -b 25 -c 18 --d 25 23`

```
script_args = '-a test -b 25 -c 18 --d 25 23'
subprocess.Popen(['/home/pi/bash/bash_script.sh', script_args])
```

I can copy the unknown option line and execute my script and the script runs without any errors and I am getting desired output.

```
 /home/pi/bash/bash_script.sh -a test -b 25 -c 18 --d 25 23
```

What am I doing incorrectly via the python script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a single argument composed of all those characters.

```
script_args = ['-a', 'test', ..., '23']
subprocess.Popen(['/home/pi/bash/bash_script.sh'] + script_args)
```

Comment: You can also unpack arguments into a list using the `*` operator which, unlike `+`, supports all iterable types. `subprocess.run(['/home/pi/bash/bash_script.sh', *script_args])`